# Firebase storage does not work when I test the game on my phone, but it works in the unity editor

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I recently came across the following problem: when I tested my game in unity editor and tried to send a file to firebase storage, it was successful, but when I tried to do the same on my phone, it didn't work. I found out by some methods that the code still finds and "sends" the necessary file when the game is running on android, but when I go to the firebase website to see if it was sent, I see a negative result. Also, in the "Usage" section, there are no new requests for storage connections.

In other words, it seems that everything works in the application, but it doesn't work when working with the service.

Here is the method that sends the file:

```
public void SaveJsonData()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.temporaryCachePath, "gameDataTemp.json");

    string jsonDataTemp = JsonUtility.ToJson(JsonStorage.instance.jsonData, true);
    // JsonStorage.instance.jsonData is a class that translates to json

    File.WriteAllText(path, jsonDataTemp);

    if (File.Exists(path) && UserData.instance.User != null)
    {
        reference.PutFileAsync(path).ContinueWith(task => 
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.Log("SAVE");
                // Checking, I came to the conclusion that on android, the code goes here
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("FAIL");
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("NULL");
    }
}
```

I also have such methods:

```
StorageReference reference;

FirebaseStorage storage;

// The method is executed after checking and fixing dependencies
public void SetStorage(FirebaseStorage stor)
{
    storage = stor;
    SetReference();
}

public void SetReference()
{
    reference = storage.RootReference.Child(UserData.instance.User.UserId).Child("gameData");
}
```

I would also like to note that I fill in the FirebaseApp in CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync myself

```
await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
            {
                initText.text = "Checking the readiness of dependencies";

                var dependencyStatus = task.Result;

                if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
                {
                    if (FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
                    {
                        Firebase.AppOptions options = new Firebase.AppOptions();

                        options.ApiKey = "(My api key)";
                        options.AppId = "(My app id)";
                        options.ProjectId = "(My project id)";
                        options.StorageBucket = "(My storage bucket)";
                        options.DatabaseUrl = new System.Uri("(Url)");

                        app = FirebaseApp.Create(options);
                    }
                    

                    storageInstance = FirebaseStorage.GetInstance(app, "(app link)");

                    isReady = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                        "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                }
            });
```

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that the problem is that RootReference is not working on the phone.

If you need any further information, please do not hesitate to ask. I would be grateful for any assistance

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please show where you are calling `SetStorage `

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. It was caused by problems with accessing files on android

How I fixed it:
In the **AndroidManifest.xml** file located in **Assets > Plugins > Android**, I added the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I would also advise you if you are looking for your file by this principle:

```
string local_file = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "yourData.json");
```

then to easily upload it to firebase storage, add

```
string local_file_uri = string.Format("{0}://{1}", Uri.UriSchemeFile, local_file);
```

and upload the file already at the local_file_uri path